# Is a suspension needed to do wheelies?

Tags: suspension

Would you recommend front suspension or back suspension to do wheelies?

I am looking for a new bike for my 13 year old.

Is the suspension bought separately from the bike?

Answer (score 8):

A wheelie is riding along on your rear wheel, using the torque from pedaling to keep the front wheel up.

A manual is rising along on your rear wheel, coasting and shifting your mass backwards behind the rear wheel to keep the front wheel up.

You do not need suspension to do wheelies or manuals. You can find an enumerable amount of videos of people on YouTube doing wheelies and manuals on full suspension mountain bikes, hardtail mountain bikes, and even fully rigid mountain bikes, trials bikes, and BMX bikes.

Generally speaking, you don't add suspension to a bike that didn't start out with it. Rear suspension has to be designed into the frame. Suspension forks can *technically* be added to almost any bike. However, frames that were not designed for front suspension will have their geometry altered and likely aren't capable of handling the forces that come along with riding that requires suspension.

Comment: Wheelies/manuals are possible on road bikes too.

Comment: Opinion: If you are buying bike for wheelies and other tricks, flatland BMX or trials it is.

Comment: Not only do you not need suspension, it usually makes it a bit harder especially when one first learned it on a rigid bike. For example when initiating a manual you can apply some downwards force to the front before lifting the bars, with front suspension the 'spring back' is juast a little bit different.